PostgreSQL Query Planner Issues: n_live_tup Mismatch (Table has 400k estimated rows but actually has 24M rows)
I'm working with PostgreSQL, and I’ve encountered a significant performance issue due to a mismatch between the statistics reported in pg_stat_user_tables and the actual data in my table.
Here’s the situation:
_ Table name: stock_out_instance
_ Reported Statistics: pg_stat_user_tables shows n_live_tup as 453255
_ Actual Rows: The table actually contains 24 millions records.
Here are the parameters: pg_stat_user_table:
enter image description here



relid
schemaname
relname
seq_scan
seq_tup_read
idx_scan
idx_tup_fetch
n_tup_ins
n_tup_upd
n_tup_del
n_tup_hot_upd
n_live_tup
n_dead_tup
n_mod_since_analyze
last_vacuum
last_autovacuum
last_analyze
last_autoanalyze
last_vacuum
autovacuum_count
analyze_count
autoanalyze_count




17110
public
stock_out_instance
136
1342260162
97443530
98530300611
465849
0
3435
0
453255
12594
460125





0
0
0



Here are the parameters table: pg_class:
enter image description here



relname
relnamespace
reltype
reloftype
relowner
relam
refilenode
retables
repages
reltupes
relallvisiable
relltoastrelid
relisshare
relpersistence
relkind
relnatts
relchecks
relhasoids
relhaspkey
relhasrule
relhastrigger
relsubclass
relrowsecurity
relforcerowsecurity
relispopulated
relreplied
relispartition
refrozendxid
relminmxid
relacl
reloptions
relpartbound




stock_out_inss
2200
17112
0
16393
0
17110
0
729126
2.51E+07
0
17115
False
p
r
22
0
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
d
FALSE
802
1






Postgres version:
PostgreSQL 10.23, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit.
Setting autovacuum: default
#autovacuum = on            # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0
                    # their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # actions running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds.
#autovacuum_max_workers = 3     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50   # min number of row updates before
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50  # min number of row updates before
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of table size before vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of table size before analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = 400000000    # maximum multixact age
                    # before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms    # default vacuum cost delay for
                    # autovacuum, in milliseconds;
                    # -1 means use vacuum_cost_delay
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1  # default vacuum cost limit for
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use

                    # vacuum_cost_limit                                                                                             

The same query but with different input data:
Plan wrong choose index:
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/b5fhbd8dff897554#plan/node/1
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/f3989affh7h29169
Plan connect choose index:
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/dg2528e13cc8144f
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/760aba0heb32312c
All table using: r update, insert, select and delete
Define table:
-- Table: public.stock_out_instance

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.stock_out_instance
(
    wh_code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    customer_code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    stock_out_no character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    loc_code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    product_no character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    serial_no character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    sub_inv_code character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    qty double precision NOT NULL,
    operated_by bigint NOT NULL,
    operated_name character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    operated_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    scanned_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    depth bigint NOT NULL,
    created_by bigint NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_by bigint NOT NULL,
    updated_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    nid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    version bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    production_date timestamp without time zone,
    expiration_date timestamp without time zone,
    date_in timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT loading_instance_pkey PRIMARY KEY (wh_code, customer_code, loc_code, product_no, serial_no, sub_inv_code, stock_out_no)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance
    OWNER to tvn;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_customer_code_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_customer_code_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_customer_code_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (customer_code COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_loc_code_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_loc_code_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_loc_code_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (loc_code COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_product_no_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_product_no_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_product_no_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (product_no COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_serial_no_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_serial_no_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_serial_no_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (serial_no COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_stock_out_no_customer_code_wh_code_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_stock_out_no_customer_code_wh_code_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_stock_out_no_customer_code_wh_code_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (stock_out_no COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, customer_code COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST, wh_code COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_stock_out_no_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_stock_out_no_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_stock_out_no_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (stock_out_no COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_sub_inv_code_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_sub_inv_code_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_sub_inv_code_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (sub_inv_code COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: stock_out_instance_wh_code_index

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS public.stock_out_instance_wh_code_index;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS stock_out_instance_wh_code_index
    ON public.stock_out_instance USING btree
    (wh_code COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

What should I do to check the cause of the problem? I read articles about PostgreSQL 9 that seem to describe the same issue, and I wonder if it has been fixed in version 10.
I want the n_live_tup value to approximate the actual row count of the table.


How did you determine?: The table actually contains 24 millions records.. 2) I am not seeing any entries for last_* and count_*. That indicates you have not done a manual vacuum or analyze and that autovacuum is not running.  Read this Autovacuum Daemon. In particular do you have track_count = on in postgresql.conf.


n_live_tup is reset to zero after a crash or immediate shutdown.  Either a VACUUM or an ANALYZE should fix it back up again.  I don't think this field is used in planning.

Please post EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output. You didn't tell, but you seem to be using an old, unsupported version of PostgreSQL. Don't do that!

@AdrianKlaver


I have based it on the count(*) query statistics and the value from pg_class.reltuples to determine the number of records in the table.
2, I am still trying to understand whether running vacuum and analyze could cause any issues with the database, and why such issues might occur. Currently, the problem is only affecting a portion of the data, not the entire project.


I have not configured track_count. As far as I know, the default value is on.



version 10 is EOL just like all the 9.x versions. Upgrade to at least version 13 to move to a supported version. When having issues with the statistics, you should first run an ANALYZE to make sure the statics are up to date.


In Postgres you need to run VACUUM and ANALYZE on a regular basis. VACUUM reclaims space from deleted tuples and ANALYZE keeps the table statistics up to date so the query planner can make the correct decisions. AUTOVACUUM does this in the background and in manner that generally does not impact performance. You run into more issues not running them then running them. 2) Look at the postgresql.conf and confirm the setting for track_counts.


@Laurenz Albe I add plan EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
